# Bash: app definitely on $path, but not found when run

Tags: python-3.x, bash, pip

I'm having a issue with a python app that I installed on a empty server.
The package I installed is `invoke` using `pip3 install invoke`

After install if I just run `invoke` without specifying the abs path, then I
get a error: `-bash: /usr/bin/invoke: No such file or directory`

Running it with the full path to the app works fine.
So I'm confused why it's ignoring the legit app that is in a location
that is definitely on the `$PATH`.

See the cli commands below for visual reference:

```
/# invoke
-bash: /usr/bin/invoke: No such file or directory

/# find -name invoke
./usr/local/bin/invoke
./usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/invoke

/# echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin

/# /usr/local/bin/invoke -V
Invoke 1.4.1
```

Anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: Have you tried `hash -r`? Looks like `/usr/bin/invoke` was hashed to `invoke` before

Comment: Does it have executable rights? - look at chmod perhaps? https://www.computerhope.com/unix/uchmod.htm Also what type of file are you finding? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/165500/234301

Comment: @oguzismail yes looks like that's it. when I just ran hash I saw the invalid path there. Hash manpage doesn't mention -r though. What does that do?

Comment: @Andre it resets all mappings, `-r` is the only standard option btw

Comment: Ty @oguzismail , that all worked. Didn't even know that this existed. Learn something new every day :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments of my original post, this was because the command was previously hashed and bash remembered the old path. Running `hash -r` was suggested, which resets all mappings. I eventually used `hash -d invoke` which cleared only that single entry. My reasoning was that I wasn't sure if anything else in the mappings were expected to be there by some other app.

**Edit**: As pointed out in the comments below, there is no harm in using `-r` since it's just a faster way to look something up and is saved there once it finds it again anyway.

Comment: The hash is only used to prevent the shell from having to perform path lookup every time a command is called. The first time you run `invoke`, the shell does path lookup and finds it in `/usr/local/bin`, so it remembers `/usr/local/bin/invoke` for the next time. No harm would come from clearing the entire cache. (Every shell instance starts with an empty cache anyway.)

Comment: Other apps aren't using the cache at all; it's an in-memory data structure for the shell only. Other applications are either doing path lookup every time, or (possibly) maintaining their own cache.